# Excel: count numbers greater than 3 in strings in range of cells

Tags: string, excel, count

I have a spreadsheet tracking games of fifa 15 between me and my friend. We track goal scorers for each game in this format

```
Messi(2), Neymar, Suarez(4)
```

Goal scorers are recorded every game
My goal is to count the number of hattricks scored total. In this particular game Suarez scored a hattrick since he score more than 3 goals. 
I am looking for a formula, any help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: What does your table look like? Do you just have this text inside a single cell?

Comment: If Messi scored 6 goals (it's possible), would that count as two hat-tricks?

Comment: Tom's answer was exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if the cells are formatted exactly as shown, you could try:-

```
=SUM(LEN(A2:A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A4,{"(3)","(4)","(5)","(6)"},"")))/3
```

where you would need to adjust the range A2:A4 to suit your data.

This assumes that even Messi is unlikely to score more than 6 goals in one match and if he did score 6 goals it would still count as one hat-trick.

It has to be entered as an array formula using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]